# show content on specific page javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress

I am trying to show a div element on a specific page e.g. -  `example.com/my-account` , right now it is showing on all my-account pages for example - `example.com/my-account/lost-password`

I know how to use JavaScript but not in webpages so can someone help me? This is how I would do it with JavaScript. I just need someone to help get this to work inside the php page I am trying to edit.

```
<script>
var cx = window.location;
var curWin = String(cx);
var myAccount = "http://example.com/my-account/";

if (curWin == myAccount){
<div id="banner"><img src="http://img.c5454o.png"></div>
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you open your developer tool, you can see that the body is assigned with classes (when using `<body <?php body_class(); ?>>`).

For example `<body class="home page page-id-7 page-template-default">`.

So from here on, you can tell css what to do like so:

```
#banner {display: none;}
body.page-id-7 #banner {display: block;}
```

So you don't realy need Javascript to detect a specific page and display a specific element.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to show a div element on specific page then create a unique id on that page like `<div id='UniqueId'>` then go to javascript code and write,

jQuery Code is:

```
if($('#UniqueId').length > 0)
{
 //show specific element

 }
```

Comment: i need to specify a specific page.

Comment: or you can do , `` var baseUrl = "http://example.com/my-account/";
 var myurl = baseUrl.substring(baseUrl.lastIndexOf('/my') + 1); if(myurl == my-account){// show element}

Comment: #uniqueId will represent your specific page if you will create #uniqueId div on that specific  page... or try my last suggestion

Answer (score 0):

Add Your condition like this

```
var cx = window.location;

if(cx.substr(-11)=="my-account/") {
   //then do whatever you want
}
```

OR if your string is without last slash then..

```
if(cx.substr(-10)=="my-account") {
   //then do whatever you want
}
```

substr(-11) function will cut your string of url from last 10 indexes so 
you can apply your contion then.

Comment: any console error?
i tested in fiddle it was working..  http://jsfiddle.net/8zw56zaL/

Comment: actually yeah i got it to work without subtracting anything, basically the same way i set it in OP but when i try to put a bunch of html code between the if statement its not working.

Comment: can you put your html code here or update your question with code which you are talking about. (bunch of html code between the if statement)